# Mail never received by gmail account

Tags: python

I'm trying to send HTML mail with Python to a gmail adress:

```
import smtplib, ssl
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

port = 587  # For starttls
#port = 465

smtp_server = "ssl0.ovh.net"
fromaddr = "xxxx@xxxxxx.com"
password = "xxxxxxx"
toaddrs = "xxxxx@gmail.com"

msg = MIMEMultipart("alternative")
msg["Subject"] = "Sujet"
msg["From"] = fromaddr
msg['To'] = ','.join(toaddrs)

html = """\<html><body><p>Hi,<br>How are you?<br><a href="http://www.realpython.com">Real Python</a> has many great tutorials.</p></body></html>"""

part = MIMEText(html, "html")
msg.attach(part)

# Create secure connection with server and send email
context = ssl.create_default_context()

try:
    server = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server, port)
    server.set_debuglevel(1) # debug
    server.ehlo()  # Can be omitted
    server.starttls(context=context)
    server.ehlo()  # Can be omitted
    server.login(fromaddr, password)
    server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg.as_string())
    server.quit()
    print('Mail sent')
except smtplib.SMTPException as e:
    print(e)
```

But I never receive mail in gmail (not in spam).

Here is debug log:

> reply: b'250-OVH SMTP PROXY Hello\r\n' reply: b'250-SIZE
> 104857600\r\n' reply: b'250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES\r\n' reply: b'250-AUTH
> LOGIN PLAIN\r\n' reply: b'250-AUTH=LOGIN PLAIN\r\n' reply:
> b'250-STARTTLS\r\n' reply: b'250 8BITMIME\r\n' reply: retcode (250);
> Msg: b'OVH SMTP PROXY Hello\nSIZE 104857600\nENHANCEDSTATUSCODES\nAUTH
> LOGIN PLAIN\nAUTH=LOGIN PLAIN\nSTARTTLS\n8BITMIME' send:
> 'STARTTLS\r\n' reply: b'220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS\r\n' reply:
> retcode (220); Msg: b'2.0.0 Ready to start TLS' reply: b'250-OVH SMTP
> PROXY Hello\r\n' reply: b'250-SIZE 104857600\r\n' reply:
> b'250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES\r\n' reply: b'250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN\r\n'
> reply: b'250-AUTH=LOGIN PLAIN\r\n' reply: b'250 8BITMIME\r\n' reply:
> retcode (250); Msg: b'OVH SMTP PROXY Hello\nSIZE
> 104857600\nENHANCEDSTATUSCODES\nAUTH LOGIN PLAIN\nAUTH=LOGIN
> PLAIN\n8BITMIME' send: 'AUTH PLAIN
> AHRoZW9AZmx5bWVmcm9tLmNvbQBDQWJ2cGdkVkY5Rkg=\r\n' reply: b'235 2.7.0
> Authentication successful\r\n' reply: retcode (235); Msg: b'2.7.0
> Authentication successful' send: 'mail FROM:xxxx@xxxxxxx.com
> size=521\r\n' reply: b'250 2.1.0 Ok\r\n' reply: retcode (250); Msg:
> b'2.1.0 Ok' send: 'rcpt TO:xxxxxxxx@gmail.com\r\n' reply: b'250
> 2.1.5 Ok\r\n' reply: retcode (250); Msg: b'2.1.5 Ok' send: 'data\r\n' reply: b'354 End data with .\r\n' reply: retcode
> (354); Msg: b'End data with .' data: (354, b'End data
> with .') send: b'Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
> boundary="===============5560189794113133871=="\r\nMIME-Version:
> 1.0\r\nSubject: Sujet\r\nFrom: xxxx@xxxx.com\r\nTo: xxxxx@gmail.com\r\n\r\n--===============5560189794113133871==\r\nContent-Type:
> text/html; charset="us-ascii"\r\nMIME-Version:
> 1.0\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n\
>
> Hi,
> How are you?
> [Real Python](http://www.realpython.com) has many great
> tutorials.
>
> \r\n--===============5560189794113133871==--\r\n.\r\n'
> reply: b'250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as ABA8D1C16293A\r\n' reply: retcode
> (250); Msg: b'2.0.0 Ok: queued as ABA8D1C16293A' data: (250, b'2.0.0
> Ok: queued as ABA8D1C16293A') send: 'quit\r\n' reply:
>
> ```
> Mail envoyé
>
> b'221 xxxxx.com Service closing transmission channel\r\n'
> reply: retcode (221); Msg: b'xxxxx.com Service closing transmission channel'
> ```

So debug log seems fine.
What can I do?

Comment: I modified: toaddrs = ["xxxxxxx@gmail.com"] ....msg['To'] = ','.join(toaddrs) but not better

Comment: Check the inbox of the account you're sending from, you might be getting a bounce message, on a delay.

Comment: Make sure to turn on less secure apps, found here: https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

Comment: in html = """ """ , isn't 3 quotations takes codes as a comment?

Comment: Try different senders and receivers. If it works then, it's not a problem in your code.

Comment: Gmail is **very strict** on filtering Spam. Are you able to send a message from that SMTP account to Gmail with a normal client?

Comment: It's really an OVH problem: with gmail smtp server (smtp.gmail.com on 465 port, I can send an email from my gmail account to the same accout gmail.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
msg.attach(MIMEText(text, 'plain'))
msg.attach(MIMEText(html, 'html'))
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.