# Error sending email from Python using EmailMessage & smtplib

Tags: python, email, smtplib

Platform: RasPi 2b / Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye) / PYTHON 3.9

I am having trouble successfully sending an email. The code appears to work, but the email is never successfully received. Spam filters are empty. I turned on smtp logging and I don't see anything obvious. Any suggestions would be appreciated. The obfuscated emails are valid. I have tried sever receivers on different smtp servers.

Here is the code snippet:

```
def send_gmail(Subject=None, Message=None, To='*******@gmail.com'):
    # Send a text email
    if Subject is None:
        return  # Nothing to do
    msg = '' if Message is None else Message
    port = 465
    smtp_server = 'mail.********.com'
    from_addr = '******@******.com'
    password = '*******'

    emsg = EmailMessage()
    emsg.set_content(msg)
    emsg['Subject'] = Subject
    emsg['From'] = from_addr
    logger.debug("Sending email to " + To)

    try:
        context = ssl.create_default_context()
        with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(smtp_server, port, context=context, timeout=5) as server:
            server.set_debuglevel(2)
            logger.debug("Logging in to mail server")
            server.login(from_addr, password)
            logger.debug("Logged in - sending message")
            server.send_message(emsg, from_addr=from_addr, to_addrs=To)
        logger.debug('Email sent to ' + To)
    except smtplib as e:
        logger.warning("Failed to send email to " + To)
        logger.exception(e)
    except Exception as e:
        logger.info("ERROR, UNEXPECTED EXCEPTION")
        logger.exception(e)
        raise e
```

The log output is:

```
Wed 03/15 11:26:11.699 [DEBUG  ]: Sending email to ****@gmail.com
Wed 03/15 11:26:12.091 [DEBUG  ]: Logging in to mail server
11:26:12.092644 send: 'ehlo [127.0.1.1]\r\n'
11:26:12.130356 reply: b'250-host2027.hostmonster.com Hello c-**-**-**-**.hsd1.nm.comcast.net **.**.**.**]\r\n'
11:26:12.130626 reply: b'250-SIZE 52428800\r\n'
11:26:12.130802 reply: b'250-8BITMIME\r\n'
11:26:12.130960 reply: b'250-PIPELINING\r\n'
11:26:12.131121 reply: b'250-PIPE_CONNECT\r\n'
11:26:12.131285 reply: b'250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN\r\n'
11:26:12.131435 reply: b'250 HELP\r\n'
11:26:12.131611 reply: retcode (250); Msg: b'host2027.hostmonster.com Hello c-**-**-**-**.hsd1.nm.comcast.net [**.**.**.**]\nSIZE 52428800\n8BITMIME\nPIPELINING\nPIPE_CONNECT\nAUTH PLAIN LOGIN\nHELP'
11:26:12.134664 send: 'AUTH PLAIN AGdhcnlAdGhlcHJhZGVzLmNvbQBVMiR0RmoyeG1CeTI=\r\n'
11:26:12.171894 reply: b'235 Authentication succeeded\r\n'
11:26:12.172265 reply: retcode (235); Msg: b'Authentication succeeded'
Wed 03/15 11:26:12.173 [DEBUG  ]: Logged in - sending message
11:26:12.177383 send: 'mail FROM:<****@*****.com> size=182\r\n'
11:26:12.210154 reply: b'250 OK\r\n'
11:26:12.210514 reply: retcode (250); Msg: b'OK'
11:26:12.211278 send: 'rcpt TO:<****@gmail.com>\r\n'
11:26:12.305768 reply: b'250 Accepted\r\n'
11:26:12.306125 reply: retcode (250); Msg: b'Accepted'
11:26:12.306402 send: 'data\r\n'
11:26:12.337775 reply: b'354 Enter message, ending with "." on a line by itself\r\n'
11:26:12.338119 reply: retcode (354); Msg: b'Enter message, ending with "." on a line by itself'
11:26:12.338356 data: (354, b'Enter message, ending with "." on a line by itself')
11:26:12.339427 send: b'Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\nMIME-Version: 1.0\r\nSubject: PowerMtr startup\r\nFrom: ****@****.com\r\n\r\nPower monitor restart complete\r\n.\r\n'
11:26:12.377185 reply: b'250 OK id=1pcUtA-003n45-AK\r\n'
11:26:12.377538 reply: retcode (250); Msg: b'OK id=1pcUtA-003n45-AK'
11:26:12.377779 data: (250, b'OK id=1pcUtA-003n45-AK')
11:26:12.378080 send: 'QUIT\r\n'
11:26:12.651751 reply: b'221 host2027.hostmonster.com closing connection\r\n'
11:26:12.652231 reply: retcode (221); Msg: b'host2027.hostmonster.com closing connection'
Wed 03/15 11:26:12.654 [DEBUG  ]: Email sent to ****@gmail.com
```

Comment: The comments (not so much the answer) here have some suggestions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66618358/mail-never-received-by-gmail-account

Comment: Everything looks fine in your log. The answer can be found in the logs of the remote SMTP server. It has accepted the message and became responsible for the delivery. Contact their admin/postmaster.

Comment: VPfB - Thanks.  I'm not real familiar with SMTP internals, but it seemed normal.  I tried it to my personal email (hosted) and to gmail - the results were the same.  I contact my hosting service and see if the can shed any light.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to fix your code, but here's my code that worked:

```
def check_change(*target_emails: str, login_email: str, password: str):
    # Some code that checked the contents of a webpage

    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(login_email, password)
    message = "Whatever you want to send"
    for email in target_emails:
        server.sendmail(login_email, email, message)
    server.quit()

    return "Function worked"
```

Comment: Thanks.  I had tried that as well, with the same results.  I went with the more formal mechanism so I could add MIME content later.